# How do I return the enum value that matches a given string?

Tags: c#, enums

So I have a string and I want to get a value from an enum to return with the same name as string. Example:

```
enum Types{
    one,
    two,
    three
}

private Types getType(string value){   //Let's say value is "two"
    return Types.value;                //This should return the enum "two" of Types
}
```

I hope I made it clear enough!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Enum.Parse

```
var t = (Types)Enum.Parse(typeof(Types), "two");
```

Comment: Yup. If you're on .NET 4+, you can also use TryParse() to avoid handling a possible exception.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I should use parse while I was trying some stuff out, but I couldn't get it to work somehow!

Comment: If you can't use `TryParse` (because you're using an old .NET), try using `Enum.IsDefined` for safety.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 4.0 or later, you can use the [Enum.TryParse<TEnum> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx):

```
Types result;

if (Enum.TryParse<Types>("two", out result))
{
     // result == Types.two
}
```